# Nginx — is it possible to allow access from certain subnets only combining with set_real_ip_from?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I need to deny access to site for all, except number of subnets, where the frontend proxies are located. At the same time I need to set real IP for further processing. The diagram looks something like this:

```
                   Some infrastructure proxying traffic to nginx
 ________         ______________________________________________             _________________
|        |       |                                              |           |                 |
| Client |------>|public-allowed ingress IP          egress IP's|<--------->| Nginx           |
|________|       |______________________________________________|           |_________________|
                                                                             Allowed access
                                                                             for «egress IP's»
                                                                             only.
```

First I tried next configuration (all IP's are for example only):

```
server {
       server_name someserver.tld;

       # Subnets where frontend proxies are located
       allow   1.2.3.0/24;
       allow   4.5.6.0/24;
       allow   7.8.9.0/24;
       
       # Deny access bypassing proxies
       deny    all;

       set_real_ip_from 1.2.3.0/24;
       set_real_ip_from 4.5.6.0/24;
       set_real_ip_from 7.8.9.0/24;
       real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
       real_ip_recursive on;

        … skipped …
}
```

As expected that's wasn't working: nginx sets the client's real IP, then checks the conditions and denies access to site for everybody. So I tried next:

```
# This block is outside of «server» section, so I expect it will be processed first
geo $someserver_allow {
        default     0;
        1.2.3.0/24  1;
        4.5.6.0/24  1;
        7.8.9.0/24  1;
}

server {
       server_name someserver.tld;

       # Deny access bypassing proxies
       if ($someserver_allow != 1) {
               return 403 "Bypassing the frontend is not allowed.";
       }

       set_real_ip_from 1.2.3.0/24;
       set_real_ip_from 4.5.6.0/24;
       set_real_ip_from 7.8.9.0/24;
       real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
       real_ip_recursive on;

        … skipped …
}
```

I expected that nginx will process `geo` instruction, setting the `$someserverallow` ignoring `real_ip_header` in `server` section, but it seems that I was wrong. To be sure I commented out entire `if` clause and added next lines right after the `geo` section:

```
map $someserver_allow $downstream {
        default $remote_addr;
}
```

And also added next in server section:

```
add_header X-Downstream-IP "$downstream"
```

Requesting the frontend server with my browser I got my own IP address in `X-Downstream-IP` header, not the IP of proxy server.

So, what's wrong with my configuration or, maybe, with my understanding of that how nginx processes instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [realip module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) is convenient when working with Nginx behind a reverse proxy or load balancer. But it does redefine `$remote_addr` which affects logging and the `allow` directive amongst others.

You can use `$realip_remote_addr` to get the address of your reverse proxy or load balancer.

You can test it using [the `geo` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html#geo) in your question, just include that variable as the address parameter.

For example:

```
geo $realip_remote_addr $someserver_allow {
    default     0;
    1.2.3.0/24  1;
    4.5.6.0/24  1;
    7.8.9.0/24  1;
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for! 
And this is exactly the case when I should read the documentation all the way through. I do use the ngx_http_realip_module, but of course I didn't read its description all the way to the "embedded variables" section.